# created a custom listview in fragment not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I created a custom listview in fragment but when i run, it's not showing anything here below is full code please help me

here is my PlanetFragment class

```html
public class PlanetFragment extends ListFragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Actors> actorList;
    ActorsAdapter adapter;
    private View view;
    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     if (view == null) {
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
         }else {
          ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
             parent.removeView(view);
  }
     
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
 
        actorList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
        adapter = new ActorsAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.row, actorList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("/UpcomingEvents/GetEvents/1");
        return view;
    }
    public class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
   HttpGet httpGs[0]);
   HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if(status == 200){
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
//     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
     for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
      JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
      Actors actor = new Actors();
      actor.setName(object.getString("eventTitle"));
     
      actorList.add(actor);
      
     }
     return true;
    }
    
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   
   return false;
  }
     
    }
}
```

here is my ActorsAdapter class

```html
public class ActorsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actors> {

 ArrayList<Actors> arraylistObject;
 int resource;
 Context context;
 ViewHolder holder;
 LayoutInflater li;
 private View view;

 public ActorsAdapter(Context context, int resource,
   ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
  super(context, resource, objects);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

  this.resource = resource;
  arraylistObject = objects;
  this.context = context;

 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  li = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  view = li.inflate(resource, parent, false);
  if (view == null) {
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   view = li.inflate(resource, parent, false);

   holder.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

   view.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
  }

  holder.tvName.setText(arraylistObject.get(position).getName());

  return view;

 }

 static class ViewHolder {

  public TextView tvName;

 }

}
```

and here is fragment_planet.xml

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.demoasynctask.MainActivity" >
    <ListView 
       android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is row.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
 
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
 
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tom Cruise"
                android:textColor="#166CED"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
 
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDateOfBirth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#D64530"
                android:text="Date of Birth: July 3, 1962" />
 
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHeight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Height: 1.80 m"
                android:textColor="#D64530"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
 
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCountry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#D64530"
                android:text="United States" />
 
        </LinearLayout>
 
    </LinearLayout>
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescriptionn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#009A57"
        android:text="Description" />
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSpouse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#166CED"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Spouse: Katie Holmes" />
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvChildren"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#166CED"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Children: Suri Cruise, Isabella Jane Cruise, Connor Cruise" />
 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have not override `getItemCount` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter for the `ListView` to update.

From the documentation of `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any `View` reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Something like this should work:

```
public class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpGet httpGs[0]);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if(status == 200){
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Actors actor = new Actors();
                    actor.setName(object.getString("eventTitle"));

                    actorList.add(actor);   
                }
                return true;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {

        // tell the adapter that its data changed
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```